# Can't add cron task in Laravel 5.0.5 on linux server

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am using **laravel 5.0.5** and I trying to run cron task on linux server. 
I can manually run commands by ssh but I can't add command to cron task.

For example:

`php artisan test_cron` works correctly (insert record to DB) but

`php artisan test_cron` returns an error:

```
-bash: app: nie znaleziono polecenia (in English: command not found)
```

and

`php artisan schedule:run` - runs all commands once but

`php artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1` is not working

Comment: The Cron will probably be run as your root user. Are you specifying a path to be used for the Cron task?

Comment: You need to put the full path to where *artisan* is. Such as `php /home/user/site/artisan test_cron`

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will try this.

Comment: @Jamesking56 Thanks but I tried this and its working but when I add five stars before php I have error: -bash: 360: without stars command is execute once.

Comment: @Gary where are you running this? The stars only take effect when placed in the `crontab`

Comment: @Gary You need to run `crontab -e` and then add the `* * * * * php artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1` line there.

Comment: @Gary see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add Laravel's scheduling command, firstly open up your crontab as follows:

`crontab -e`

Then add the following line changing the artisan path to where you have placed your site:

`* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Then hit save and you should have a message from the `crontab`:

`crontab: installing new crontab`

You should then confirm this by scheduling a task in Laravel to send you an email every 5 minutes or something.

Comment: Why would you advise addind the job to the root crontab if there's no specified need for elevated permissions?

Comment: Why would you add it to a specific user? The task shouldn't belong to an individual user as it is a system-based task.

Comment: Because the OP didn't specify what the command will do, so allowing it to run as root might have security risks. Also, where in the question does it say it's a system based task, and even if it was why would it need elevated permission anyway?

Comment: The command being run is a built-in task provided by Laravel. It allows the user to define their own schedule in Laravel's `Kernel.php` file. If there were 3 developers using his server, that cron is for the Laravel installation not an individual user.

Comment: Point taken. But in my experience it's not common practice to just add all developer accounts to `/etc/sudoers`? So only specific users might have access anyway, and the ones with root acccess don't really care in what crontab the job is placed.

Comment: That is my point, if you add it to the `root` crontab, people with `sudo` access can modify it but people without it can't. I can see what you mean by saying that since he added it, it should belong to his user but if its system-related, any administrators of the server should be able to modify it without needing to go to his specific account.

Comment: To answer this discussion, I would say its entirely up to the OP where to place `crontab` line since its his server. I guess it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @Jamesking56 when I run  'sudo crontab -e' I have: 'myLogin  is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.' Does that mean I do not have the required permissions?

Comment: @Jamesking56 If you add it to the `userx` account, still only `userx` and people with `sudo` access can access it, so it's the same as what you're saying as far as access goes, with the noted difference that the command when run as `userx` can't do as much damage as when run as `root`, this being my point. But I agree with your last comment that it's not up to us to decide that, I just thought it should be mentioned.

Comment: @Gary it seems you don't have `sudo` access on your server. You can do `crontab -e` instead.

Comment: @Bogdan @Gary I have updated my answer to exclude `sudo` access.

Comment: @Jamesking56 Thank you! I do it and I have message `crontab: installing new crontab` but I have no new cron in my cron panel and task scheduling still not working.

Comment: That command above basically allows you to define your own schedule and 'cron' inside Laravel's 'Kernel.php' file

Comment: Ok, but I have one in Kernel.php in schedule method `$schedule->command('test_cron')->cron('* * * * * *');`

Comment: I take this from [Laravel Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) in Schedule Frequency Options section. I  will try with 5 star later.